# Shimming jQuery nodes for browserify

Tags: jquery, node.js, browserify-shim

I have a file that requires a module I installed from NPM:

```
-- login.js --
require('jquery-form');
```

the module relies on the jQuery variable existing in the `window` scope but as I'm browserifying this, I understand I need to shim it.  thus I've installed browserify-shim and am using it like this (from the package.json):

```
"browserify-shim": {
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js": "jQuery"
},
```

however, when `jquery-form` runs, `jQuery` is not defined.  what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to "Shim" jQuery as a dependency of `jquery-form`. <s>If these are all installed via npm there is no need for the `browser` directive.</s> Because `jquery-form` doesn't have a `main` directive in its `package.json` you need to add the `browser` directive to show Browserify what file to include in your bundle.

```
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery-form": {
    "depends": ["jquery"]
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
},
"browser": {
  "jquery-form": "./node_modules/jquery-form/jquery.form.js"
},
```

See [this section](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-config-inside-packagejson-without-aliases) of the docs.

Comment: this is curious construction (in the depends clause): `"jquery: $"` - how does that work?  also, do I need to mess with `$`? because _jquery-form_ relies on `jQuery` not on `$`

Comment: @ekkis you're correct - in that case you do not need to export `jQuery` as `$` at all, and can just depend on `jquery` in your `depends` directive. I did a quick test and you do need the `browser` directive because of the explanation I've added above.

Comment: my copy of query-form does have a main directive, which points to `./jquery.form.js` - I'm using npmVersion 1.3.24.  interestingly, I also see `dependencies: { jquery: ">=1.5"}` in the `package.json`, so would I still need to indicate the dependency?

Comment: @ekkis I don't see that release for [this library](https://github.com/malsup/form) - is that the one you're using? If not let me know which one?

Comment: yes, that's the one I'm using.  what's odd is that when I look at the `package.json`, it doesn't look like what's in github, primarily in that mine has a whole bunch of _ keys e.g. _args, _from, _inCache, etc. and I can see that in github there's no `main`... but mine has one

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
  }
}
```

and when you require:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

Comment: the "browser" keyword allows me to swap the file that the jquery package exports when I require it right? so in this case I'm saying to use the ../dist/jquery.js whenever the jquery package is required.  but this is the file that is in the "main" of package.json and thus I shouldn't need the "browser" keyword (it's why I didn't include it) - correct? or am I wrong?

Comment: also if I `var $ = require('jquery')` (I take it this has to be done right before I `require('jquery-form')`) then what is the function of the `"browserify-shim": { "jquery": "$" }`?

Comment: in any case, I tried it but to no avail.  the `jquery-form` module needs to see `jQuery` instead of `$` so I tried `"browserify-shim": { "jquery": "jQuery" }` without success.  I also tried `jQuery = require('jquery')` (instead of `var jQuery ...`) thinking that would put it on the global scope but it still won't work.  what am I missing?